# How do I Moq a method that has an optional argument in its signature without explicitly specifying it or using an overload?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Given the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Foo(string a, bool b = false);
}
```

Attempting to mock it using Moq:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(mock => mock.Foo(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
```

gives the following error at compile time:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

I've found the issue above raised as an [enhancement](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=284) in Moq's list of issues and it appears to be assigned to the 4.5 release (whenever that is).

My question is: what should I do given that the above is not going to be fixed anytime soon? Are my options only to either explicitly set the default value of the optional parameter every time I mock it (which kind of defeats the point of specifying one in the first place) or to create an overload without the bool (like what I would have done prior to C# 4)?

Or has anyone come across a more clever way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to just specify It.IsAny<bool>() for the second parameter?

Comment: A year and half later this is still true..

Comment: @Mukus, feel free to drop a PR, bro.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I believe your only choice right now is to explicitly include the `bool` parameter in the setup for `Foo`.

I don't think it defeats the purpose of specifying a default value. The default value is a convenience for calling code, but I think that you should be explicit in your tests. Say you could leave out specifying the `bool` parameter. What happens if, in future, someone changes the default value of `b` to `true`? This will lead to failing tests (and rightfully so), but they will be more difficult to fix because of the hidden assumption that `b` is `false`. Explicitly specifying the `bool` parameter has another benefit: it improves the readability of your tests. Someone going through them will quickly know that there's one `Foo` function that accepts two parameters. That's my 2 cents, at least :)

As for specifying it every time you mock it, don't duplicate code: create and/or initialise the mock in a function, so that you only have a single point of change. If you really want to, you can overcome Moq's apparent short-coming here by duplicating `Foo`'s parameters into this initialisation function:

```
public void InitFooFuncOnFooMock(Mock<IFoo> fooMock, string a, bool b = false)
{
    if(!b)
    {
        fooMock.Setup(mock => mock.Foo(a, b)).Returns(false);
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer; I already went ahead and specified it explicitly in my mocks but your answer confirms in a very clear and logical fashion why I should do it this way. Thanks, @Chris.

Comment: changing a default parameter "should" break tests. Not having tests fail when a default is changed can be a sign of bad testing. The code may use the defaults but the tests do not?

Comment: Been a while, but I've tried this approach with Moq when trying to mock an interface (IDConnection in Dapper) and I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas why? Sample line: mockDB.Setup(x => x.Query<MyObject>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DynamicParameters>(), It.IsAny<IDbTransaction>(), false, 600)).Returns(new List<MyObject>()); The last two values are the optional parameters on the method I'm setting up.

Comment: Hmmm. Is Query<T> an extension method? Could you try using `It.Is<bool>(b => b == false), It.Is<int>(i => i == 600)` in place of `false, 600`, please? Are you certain you're not missing another optional parameter after `600`?

Comment: Ah, `Query<T>` is an extension method by the looks of it. You won't be able to mock it :( Use [Dapper Wrapper](https://github.com/half-ogre/dapper-wrapper/tree/master/DapperWrapper) - you can mock `Query<T>` on `IDbExecutor`.

Comment: Arrgggh! The horrible `if (!x) {} else {}` anti-pattern :)

Comment: @PopCatalin Yes, changing a default parameter should break tests. I've changed my wording to clarify what I meant (better late than never :)

Comment: @nicodemus13 Yes, but I was trying to keep the code example as close to the OP's example in the question as possible. I wouldn't necessarily advocate it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, providing an explicit value for the optional parameter doesn't work in the case that it's a delegate argument. You still get a MissingMethodException.

Comment: The larger issue is that if I have an existing test base (with lots of tests) and I add an optional parameter, I should not be required to change all of my existing tests to be explicit -- just as I do not change my existing production code.

Answer (score 10):

Using Moq version 4.10.1 I have been able to do the following

With Interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Foo(string a, bool b = false);
}
```

And Mock

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(mock => mock.Foo(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(false);
```

Resolves a call to Foo with the first parameter okay

Comment: True, but the answer is still useful because it fails at verify.                      
mock.Verify(mock => mock.Foo("test string"), Times.Once()); //generates the error                mock.Verify(mock => mock.Foo("test string", false), Times.Once();   ///works fine

Answer (score 9):

Just encountered this issue today, Moq doesn't support this use case.
So, seems that overriding the method would be sufficient for this case.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Foo(string a);

    bool Foo(string a, bool b);
}
```

Now both methods are available and this example would work:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(mock => mock.Foo(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to mock a call to a method such as `DoSomething(string arg = null)` for which you are not passing in an argument, simply use `?` like so:

```
mockClass.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string?>())).ReturnsAsync(mockResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my problem was that I forgot to include an `It.IsAny<string>()` call for one of my optional parameters. Once I had an `It.Is...` call for all of my parameters (including the optional ones) it compiled just fine.

Comment: Compiling fine isn't same as it actually being overridden to the mocked method.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your method is defined in your interface like below

```
Task<IDataResult<StripeSubModel>> CancelSub(List<string> list, bool? revert = false);
```

You can define your mock service like below

```
mockService.Setup(s => s.CancelSub(It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
```