# Mocking Excel's Comment.Text() in c# with moq

Tags: c#, excel, comments, moq

Currently I am trying to mock the Text() method from Excel's Comment interface in C# with moq.
[MSDN link to Text()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.comment.text.aspx)

My problem is, that I have to call it with no parameters because I just want to read the content. When calling Text() like this: `mockComment.Setup(m => m.Text()).Returns("test comment")` the following error is shown:

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments

How can I call Text() so that moq can mock this method?

I am aware of this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957537/how-do-i-moq-a-method-that-has-an-optional-argument-in-its-signature-without-exp) but my problem is that i do not have parameters to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLR` does not support calling methods with `optional arguments` either when the arguments are not provided `explicitly`, since for `IL-compiled code` the `C# compiler` inserts the default values at `compile` time.

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call.aspx), as it states that the `underlying expression tree API` does not support `optional arguments`.

Comment: So is there no way to call Text() via moq?

Comment: Yes, No way to call `Text()` via `moq`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to get around this issue via a model change.