# moq testing with an asynchronous operation does not work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I'm trying to mock test with an asynchronous method but i don't know how to set up the moq test to allow it.

```
noSQLProvider.Setup(x => x.CreateDocumentAsync(It.IsIn<Uri>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns();
```

the error is telling me:

> Usage: ResourceResponse x = await CreatDocumentAsync(...);
>
> an expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses
>   optional arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Moq a method that has an optional argument in its signature without explicitly specifying it or using an overload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957537/how-do-i-moq-a-method-that-has-an-optional-argument-in-its-signature-without-exp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentasync.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.CreateDocumentAsync%28System.Uri,System.Object,Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions,System.Boolean%29)?

In which case the error message is telling you quite clearly that that method has optional parameters and you need to be explicit about them:

```
noSQLProvider.Setup(x => x.CreateDocumentAsync(It.IsIn<Uri>(),
                                               It.IsAny<object>(),
                                               It.IsAny<RequestOptions>(),
                                               It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns();
```

This is a limitation that isn't related to async.

NB - I'm not sure on how `It.IsAny` comparison behaves for nulls, so you might have to replace `It.IsAny<RequestOptions>()` with something that explicitly sets up that parameter to be null (which is the default).

Comment: Since you're here, do you know what to put in the .Returns() bit?

Comment: Whatever you want your mock to return!

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: @AntP Afaik `It.IsAny<type>()` works fine for nulls, at least it does for me.

Comment: @Callum in your example, you are mocking the method `CreateDocumentAsync` so your `.Returns` could return a new document.